# How to execute specific method implicitly before interacting with element in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

The application I'm automating is using jQuery and ajax calls. Hence before interacting with elements, I wait for document to be ready and all ajax calls to complete. Only then I interact with element like `sendKeys()`, `click()` etc

For this, I need to add that method (say `waitForDocumentReadyAndAjaxTocomplete()`) explicitly everywhere  wherever element is being interacted.

Is there anyway I can call that method `waitForDocumentReadyAndAjaxTocomplete()` implicitly before interacting with an element?

Comment: Do you need to wait, because the elements are not yet on the page, or do the elements exist, but you need to wait for event handlers to be bound before interacting with them?

Comment: Which programming language are you using to interact with Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way. You can create an utility class which creates your identifier using the locator you want to use and in the method where you create the identifier you can call the waitForDocumentReadyAndAjaxTocomplete method.

Basically the utility class will handle the call and you can actually have a try catch or a polling mechanism to optimize the call to the method as suits your requirement.

This way you donot have to call the waitForDocumentReadyAndAjaxTocomplete method everytime. It will be called in your utility class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the power of `PageFactory.initElements(..)` where you can:

1. Design your bindings in Page Object pattern
2. Intitialize elements of your page classes using your custom `ElementLocatorFactory` / `ElementLocator`. Where you can can add waiting of your dom events before finding elements.

You can check how `AjaxElementLocatorFactory` is implemented. There should not be issues with following this approach sine all key methods are public so can be simply overriden.

However I guess you will have to supply `@CacheLookup` annotation to all your fields annotated with `@FindBy`